# Application runs but dosent have a location

Tags: android

I have this weird problem that only happens with one project. The app is launched and works perfectly fine but is not on the phone :

[image]
[image]

Here you can see that the app nono works on the phone and is running, yet it isn't located on the phone like the other 2 projects I have Boccia and Hello.
I tried this on a physical phone and it's the same issue, the app works but isn't on it.
How do I fix it

Logcat is empty for some reason

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="message/rfc822"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Activity inside the manifest

Comment: nice pictures. wanna talk some code now or logcat stacktrace instead?

Comment: "yet it isn't located on the phone like the other 2 projects I have Boccia and Hello" -- the screenshot on the right looks like the app drawer for a launcher. Either your app does not have a launcher activity, or it does and the app drawer is not up to date for some reason.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski there is not errors in the logcat everything is white. What do you want to see in it ?

Comment: @CommonsWare how can I check this? I posted the activity section from the manifest above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```xml
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="message/rfc822"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

with:

```xml
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="message/rfc822"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. What exactly changes when you separate the intent filter into 2 instead of one having everything?

Comment: @TTiM3R: Each `<intent-filter>` says "these are the rules for what I should match". Your original one said "the `Intent` must be `MAIN` or `SEND`, and be in either the category of `LAUNCHER` or `DEFAULT`, and must have a MIME type of `message/rfc822`". Few if any app launchers are going to be looking for activities that support that structure, because launcher activities do not use MIME types as a filter. The replacement is split into two distinct rules: `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` and `SEND`/`DEFAULT`/`message/rfc822`. Now, your activity matches on `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER`, which is what launchers will use.